# Hacer común una clase a todos los formularios

Tags: c#

Tengo una clase "Viaje.cs" que contiene todos los datos de un viaje

```
public int idViaje, idAgencia, ....
public string Informacion....;
```

Y luego, tengo un formulario princial en el que guardo los nuevos viajes. Vale, pues en este formulario principal tengo acceso a otros subformularios en los que elegir opciones para configurar el viaje. El caso es que cada vez que hago algo lo guardo en la clase

```
clases.Viaje oViaje = new clases.Viaje();

oCrucero.Informacion = "<p><span class='TextoFechaViaje'>INCLUYE</span></p><ul class...
```

Vale, pues por ejemplo, esta propiedad Informacion me gustaria que se viera en otro subformulario al acceder a él, pero la aplicación cuándo llamo a este subformulario me devuelve la propiedad en blanco , entonces, de ahí mi pregunta ¿Como hago común a todos los formularios y subformularios la clase viaje?

Espero haberme explicado claramente

Gracias

Comment: No haces comun la clase viaje, si no que tenes dos opciones. O guardas los datos en tu base de datos y el nuevo formulario recibe un id y la consulta, o le pasas a tus subformularios el objeto que tiene los datos... Podrias hacer la clase estatica, perooooo.. no se si tu modelo de programacion lo tolera... habria que ver tu arquitectura...

Comment: Apoyo la opcion 1 propuesta por gbianchi. Consultar los datos en cada pantalla por medio del id que vas pasando de objeto a objeto.